# Ruby on Rails newbie: how to get decent error reporting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel, webrick

So today I've been working with RoR for the first time using the book 'Rails for PHP developers'. I'm following the tutorial in there.

I created a project, with a model `Subscriber` and a controller `Subscribers`, which has a method `create`. Then I ran `ruby script/server` to launch Mongrel.

Now, the book says that if I go to http://localhost:3000/subscribers/create I should get an error because there's no template associated (yet) for this action. The book shows this error message:

> **Template missing**
>   Missing template subscribers/create.html.erb in view path /Users/derek/work/newsletter/app/views

A nice descriptive error message, really helpful. But the error I get is:

> **We're sorry, but something went wrong.**
>   We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.

That error is not helpful at all. I suspect it has to do with the fact that the book uses WEBrick, and I use Mongrel. But I assume it should be possible to get more descriptive errors, right? It seems quite painful to develop with errors like this.

Comment: "how to get decent error reporting?" How? Put in decent errors!? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some of your Rails install is semi borked. You might be missing the mysql gem or might not have the mysql ActiveRecord adaptor configured correctly.

Use gem list to see the gems you have installed

```
$ sudo gem list
```

you can use the gem install command to install or update gems

```
$ sudo gem install rails mysql
```

You usually want to install gems with sudo (as root) so all users can use them ( like apache or www-data)

Im sorry your first try at Rails hasn't gone smoothly, trust me it is an extremely powerful framework. Strick with it!

Comment: The mysql gem was indeed not installed properly. I found an excellent tutorial on how to fix this here: http://techliberty.blogspot.com/2009/12/dealing-with-rake-aborted-uninitialized.html

Comment: NOTE: the newest version of rails is 3 something and your book probably uses 2.3.5 or around there. There are LARGE differences.

use 
$ sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.5 
to install a specific version

you might want to uninstall any version you want want just in case

$ sudo gem uninstall rails
and it will give you an interactive menu.

NOTE the --no-ri and --no-rdoc flags will make it go faster.
e.g. sudo gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to setup the database. You can check log/development.log for further details.

Comment: I have set up the database. The development log says this: `Status: 500 Internal Server Error uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes`

Comment: And what happens when you run rake db:migrate ?

Comment: `rake aborted! uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes (See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Answer (score 0):

you only get the first message if you are running in development mode.

Comment: How do I get in development mode?

Comment: I think I am already in development mode, because I get messages in development.log but nog in test.log and production.log

Comment: script/server defaults to development.

the rails 3 convention is rails server but does the same thing. Your book probably teaches rails 2.3.x